# Можно ли использовать typescript без requireJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть два класса:

```
export class ActionsCollection{
    constructor(greeting :string){
        this.greet(greeting);
    }

    public greet(greeting :string) {
        return "<h1>"+greeting+"</h1>";
    }
}
```

и:

```
import {ActionsCollection} from "./actionsCollection";

class Greeter extends ActionsCollection{
    constructor(public greeting: string) {
        super(greeting); 
    }
}

alert(new Greeter("Hello, world!"));
```

`Greeter` генерится в такой файл, в котором есть строка `require("./actionsCollection")`. Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы все эти файлы (*.ts) генерились в один какой-нибудь `main.js`, при этом не нужен будет никакой `require`.

Можно ли так сделать? И если да то как?

Comment: Генерится **чем**? Какой командой собирается код? Какой версией TS?

Comment: @D-side Последняя версия, генерятся в ide webstorm 2016. Но можно и с помощью gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Какой-то загрузчик модулей всё равно потребуется.** В TypeScript 1.8 добавили возможность склеить модули в один файл для форматов `amd` и `system` (`--module`&`--outFile`), но соответствующий загрузчик модулей нужен даже в этой ситуации.

Так что вам придётся подвергнуть результат работы компилятора TypeScript дополнительной обработке "упаковщиком" вроде Webpack или Browserify. К примеру, вот (чуть поправленная) конфигурация Webpack для сборки TypeScript в один файл, [опубликованная James Brantly](http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/):

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {  
  entry: './src/greeter.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0"
  }
}
```

---

`дерево проекта`

```
example
|= src
|  |- greeter.ts
|  |- actionsCollection.ts
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
|- bundle.js  (генерируется webpack'ом, изначально отсутствует)
```

В результате после запуска `webpack` сгенерируется автономный (на уровне браузера) `bundle.js`. А `webpack --watch` будет генерировать файлик заново при сохранении составляющих.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что без require не обойтись в любом случае? (это странно, ведь это нормально когда все скрипты мининифицированы в один). Просто при `import` - он заменяет в js файле на `require()`

Comment: @sanu0074 эм, **на выходе из `tsc`** всегда будут модули, тип модулей зависит от флагов компиляции. А уже модули `webpack` склеивает между собой в один автономный файл со своим упрощённым аналогом `require`. Вот. Результат можно минифицировать и оно станет ещё меньше.

Comment: а можно ли сделать это, ограничившись только gulp'om? (я знаю, вопрос выглядит глупо, но все же он актуален)

Comment: @sanu0074 естественно. Gulp же сам ничего не делает, только координирует. Поставить плагин для Gulp, подкрутить сборку и всё.

Comment: если вам не сложно, вы бы могли начеркать пример конфига для gulp'a который бы, компилил все файлы из дирректории `./ts` в один файл `./js/main.js` например?

Comment: @sanu0074 сложно, я ни в Gulp, ни в Webpack не умею. Но означенный конфиг вебпака уже работает, [сослаться на результат из Gulp должно быть несложно](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream/blob/master/readme.md).

Answer (score -2):

Вам потребуется:

- Node.js
- NPM

Далее через пакетный менеджер npm устанавливаем **gulp** глобально

`sudo npm install -g gulp`

Переходим в папку проекта:

`npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-tsc`

Создаем файл **gulpfile.js** для всех наших задач для **gulp** и записываем в него следующее:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

gulp.task('build-tsc', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['build-tsc']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build-tsc', 'watch']);
```

`build-tsc` - компилит все наши .ts файлы

`watch` - отслеживает изменения в файлах и перезапускает компиляцию (чтобы постоянно не перезапускать скрипт

---

После того как настроили все наши таски (задачи) запускаем gulp в терминале:

`gulp`

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто :) Нет, это скомпилирует в RequireJS-модули.

Comment: С чего это вдруг? о_О Видимо в typescript много что поменялось за год. Но это бред) раньше такого не было.
Как вариант могу предложить WebStorm. Там есть встроенная компиляция TypeScript

Comment: В гугле на удивление много вопросов с компиляцией TS в один файл, так что такая ситуация существует уже давно .-. Но что я распинаюсь, собстна, я проверил, генерит модули, без загрузчика не работает. Можете проверить сами и тоже убедиться :)